# How to map the touch screen event to virtual key event(eg: back, home, menu)?

Tags: android, dictionary, touchscreen

Environment: android platform;
Maybe you know that the command of "getevent" can output the events got from "/dev/input/eventX". Some devices have virtual keys like back, menu, home etc, and these keys implement also through touch screen. So how can i map the touch screen event at the virtual key area to right key event(back->back, home->home, menu->menu etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
}
```

Home: Impossible

Comment: Thanks! But Sorry! I can get the touch screen event of virtual button like back/memu/home at PC end not android device, then i want to map the coordinates to key code of back/menu/home. but i don't know the rules how to map. (Maybe the driver and framework maintain the rules, i mean i need the rules, it's hard to find out the rules from android source code.)